# Callback api google

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js

i'm trying to use google's api matrix of distance to retrieve meters from two geopoint but the callback function never be called. Maybe a scope issue?

```
   prove: function(){


      var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087, 40.087);
      var destination= new google.maps.LatLng(38, 39);

      function calculateDistances() {
       var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
       service.getDistanceMatrix(
       {
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
       }, callback);        <--netbeans tell me callback is not declared
                                    }


     function callback(response, status) {
      console.log("incallback");             <---never called

                                         }




              }
```

Comment: Just a comment, would be easier if you formatted your code

Comment: You aren't passing any parameters to your callback, for one.  See this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061990/javascript-pass-parameter-to-callback-or-set-variable-value-in-distancematrixsta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your calculateDistances() is also not being called. am I correct?

It is because, you have just declared your functions but aren't calling calculateDistances anywhere. Put a calculateDistances(); in prove:function(){} and it should work

Comment: I can't get distance...it return zero results why?

Comment: Might be because the origin and destination couldn't be found. Have you tried console logging the response?

Comment: Your query results **ZERO_RESULTS** element status code which as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_element_status_codes) says that there is no route found between these two points.